# convert base64 to real image and save in a folder php

Tags: php

I found the below php file upload from the web and it worked fine till i designed a web application in angular 4 which a photo before being upload will have to be cropped. When the image is cropped, it saves the cropped image in a base64 format, now my problem is how i can configure my current php script to convert the base64 image to a real image

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
  echo json_encode(array('status' => false));
  exit;
}

$path = '../myapp/img_folder/';

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
  $originalName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $ext = '.'.pathinfo($originalName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $generatedName = md5($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']).$ext;
  $filePath = $path.$generatedName;

  if (!is_writable($path)) {
    echo json_encode(array(
      'status' => false,
      'msg'    => 'Destination directory not writable.'
    ));
    exit;
  }

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $filePath)) {
    echo json_encode(array(
      'status'        => true,
      'originalName'  => $originalName,
      'generatedName' => $generatedName
    ));
  }
}
else {
  echo json_encode(
    array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'No file uploaded.')
  );
  exit;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to; Base64 images can be loaded directly inside of an `<img />` tag. If the value is getting stored in the database Base64-encoded, simply load it as you would any other image (making sure to include the Base64 prefix). If you **really** want to convert back, you can use [**`base64_decode()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Answer (score 4):

**Here is the solution for your problem. Tested and Working Properly.**

```
$encoded = "encoded---text---here===";
$file = fopen("mypicture.png", "w"); //(you can put jpg, png or any other extension)
fwrite($file, base64_decode($encoded));
fclose($file);
```

Comment: can you place the code into my script, because i'm kinda confused

Comment: You said that cropped image is saved as base64 encoded string. Where are you getting the base64 string?